# To evaluate equivalent resistance of the circuit by star delta method

Tags: resistors, resistance

How do I evaluate this circuit via star delta method?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?  Explain how you have tried to solve it, and where you got stuck.

Comment: @jre thanks for formatting my question. I converted 4 5 3 Junction in delta. Then I have serious problems evaluating the circuit ie is the 8 ohm in series or parallel.

Comment: Ok.  That belongs in the question.  You can edit it in.